# Replace characters in a hapmap data set

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, replace, bioinformatics

I am thinking to use a bash code to solve the following issue in my data.

Considering the bellow data set in hapmap format in which I need to replace some  characters (letters in this case) based on the data of the column "alleles". Data in the column "alleles" will be a combination in pairs of four letters (A, G, C, and T).

```
rs#    alleles  chro    pos    ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4 ind5 ind6. . 
mar_1   G/T     1       2386806 G    T    T    G   K    T    
mar_2   T/G     1       2386848 T    G    T    K   T    K
mar_3   G/T     1       2387553 T    K    G    K   T    G
mar_4   G/A     1       2564608 G    G    G    N   R    A
mar_5   C/T     1       2564616 C    Y    C    Y   T    N
.
.
```

What I want to get is a code that go through the entire row (in the case of row 1) and when it find a letter "T" (letter after the "/") replace it by a letter "G" (letter before the "/") and when it find either a letter "R", "Y", "S", "W", "K", or "M" replace it by "T" (letter after "/").

In other words the code has to find (in each row) all the letters that match with the letter after the "/" (in the column "alleles") and replace them by a letter that match with the letter before the "/". And, when it finds a letter that match with one of these: ("R","Y", "S", "W", "K", or "M") it has to replace it by a letter that match with the one after the "/".

The output I would like to get is:

```
rs#    alleles  chro    pos    ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4 ind5 ind6. . 
mar_1   G/T     1       2386806 G    G    G    G   T    G    
mar_2   T/G     1       2386848 T    T    T    G   T    G
mar_3   G/T     1       2387553 G    T    G    T   G    G
mar_4   G/A     1       2564608 G    G    G    N   A    G
mar_5   C/T     1       2564616 C    T    C    T   C    N
.
.
```

Note: The "N" means a missing value, so it has to be kept such is it.

Any help with this issue will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output. That way we can be sure that we've understood your requirements. I read your description twice (and I actually work in the field) and I don't understand exactly what you need.

Comment: I already edited my question, hopefully is clearer now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -F'\s+|/' -lape '
     s/^(\S+\s+){4}\K.*/$&=~s|$F[2]|$F[1]|gr/e;
     s/^(\S+\s+){4}\K.*/$&=~s|[RYSWKM]|$F[2]|gr/e
  ' ip.txt
rs#    alleles  chro    pos    ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4 ind5 ind6. . 
mar_1   G/T     1       2386806 G    G    G    G   T    G    
mar_2   T/G     1       2386848 T    T    T    G   T    G
mar_3   G/T     1       2387553 G    T    G    T   G    G
mar_4   G/A     1       2564608 G    G    G    N   A    G
mar_5   C/T     1       2564616 C    T    C    T   C    N
```

- `-F'\s+|/'` split input line on white spaces or the `/` character, saved in `@F` array
- `^(\S+\s+){4}\K.*` will get all columns except the first four
- `$&=~s|$F[2]|$F[1]` on the matched portion (columns except first four) perform another substitution

  - `$F[2]` will contain the character after `/` and `$F[1]` will contain the character before `/`
- The `r` modifier returns the final substituted string and `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- Since same pattern is used again, the second substitution can also be shortened to `s//$&=~s|[RYSWKM]|$F[2]|gr/e`
- See [command switches](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for explanation on `-lape` options

Comment: I am getting this error:
     Bad name after F 'at recode.pl line 2

Although I have to admit my knowledge of Perl is 0

Comment: not sure, may be copy paste error? try as one-liner.. `perl -F'\s+|/' -lape 's/^(\S+\s+){4}\K.*/$&=~s|$F[2]|$F[1]|gr/e;s//$&=~s|[RYSWKM]|$F[2]|gr/e' ip.txt` and what is your perl version? mine is `v5.22.1`

Comment: One-liner works very well, great!  My Perl version is v5.16.3  Just for curiosity, do you think my previous error was due to the version?  Thanks

Comment: no idea.. both work for me..

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'/(\s+|\/)/' -lne '
   print @F[0..9], map { s/($F[4])|([RYSWKM])/$2?$F[4]:$F[2]/re } @F[10..$#F];
' hapmap.txt

sed -e '
   s/^\(\S\+\s\+\)\{4\}/&\n/                           # mark col-4

  :a
  s|^\(\S\+\s\+\(.\)/\(.\).*\n.*\)\3|\1\2|g;ta         # perform sub-1

  :b
  s|^\(\S\+\s\+\(.\)/\(.\).*\n.*\)[RYSWKM]|\1\3|g;tb   # perform sub-2

  s/\n//g                                              # throw away marker
' hap_map.txt
```